Can you enable strict Int32/Int64 type compatiblity in Delphi 12?
I am migrating a whole lot of classes to Int64 from Integer which in my 32 bit application are 32 bit.
I would like the compiler to throw an exception if I pass an Integer which is 32 bit to a procedure whose type parameter is explictly defined as Int64 but as Int32 is Int64 compatible no error is shown.
I want to do this so I can make sure I don't miss any references.

The only way you can do that is to make the parameter a VAR parameter, but this will prevent you from passing constants or calculations. If that is an issue, there unfortunately isn't any way to do what you wish.

Safe implicit conversions cannot be detected, because they cannot do any harm. Would you accept such an error when you call such a procedure with a 32-bit literal? My impression is that you are trying to solve a different problem here.

I thnk you can do something like TStrictInt64 = type Int64.  And change your method signatures to use TStrictInt64. But then you must pass in a TStrictInt64 to each method. You can wrap all regular Int64 with a cast TStrictInt64(variable) before the call. Its annoying, but at least then the compiler can help you and you can remove all the TStrictInt64 at the end.

This doesn't seem like it's going to lead to better code in the long run. What problem do you envisage if you do pass a 32 bit integer to a 64 bit parameter.

@DaveNovo: No - the TStrictInt64 = type Int64 is still assignment compatible with Int64 (and all other Int-types). It will only block for VAR/OUT parameters, not CONST/not-specified Int64 parameters, just like a general Int64 parameter. Just like type TDateTime = type Double still allows you to do a TDateTimeVar := DoubleVar; but not a TryStrToDateTime(StringExpr,DoubleVar)

You could get the desired information by making use of Method Overloading which will make sure that Delphi executes the overloaded method whose input parameter types matches to the passed parameter types.
Then for any of the overloaded methods whose input parameters does not match your desired input parameters you mark such methods as deprecated. This is going to create W1000 Symbol '%s' is deprecated (Delphi) anywhere where such overloaded method is called.
Now the caveat with this approach is that you may need to make 8 overloaded versions of your methods in order to cover four signed integer types (Int8, Int16, Int32 and Int64) as well as four unsigned integer types (UInt8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64);
Here is a small example of four overloaded methods detecting 4 signed integer types:
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure Test(I: Int8); overload; deprecated;
    procedure Test(I: Int16); overload; deprecated;
    procedure Test(I: Int32); overload; deprecated;
    procedure Test(I: Int64); overload;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

procedure TForm1.Test(I: ShortInt);
begin
  MessageDlg('8 bit integer',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Test(I: Int16);
begin
  MessageDlg('16 bit integer',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Test(I: Int32);
begin
  MessageDlg('32 bit integer',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Test(I: Int64);
begin
  MessageDlg('64 bit integer',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ShI: ShortInt;
    SmI: SmallInt;
    I: Integer;
    I64: Int64;
    NatI: NativeInt;
begin
  Test(ShI);
  Test(SmI);
  Test(I);
  Test(I64);
  Test(NatI);
end;

Note that with last test call the returned value for NativeInt depends on whether your application is compiled for 32 bit or 64 bit architecture as is expected.

Exactly what I wanted. After migration I can then remove the deprecated procedure.
This helps me find places where a range check error could come up in future.

@RichardShuck: Just beware, that a call with an expression (or a constant) will most likely lead to a compiler error "ambigious overload" (untested)
